# In react-native, is it anyway I can pull data from my JSON into my component?

Tags: react-native, react-router, react-navigation

Here is a thing, I'am struggling about using RN .

1. I would like to use flatlist to generate my content.
2. the flatlist contents can be pressed so It makes to go another page open.
3. I need animation freedom so the content can be pop up anywhere such as from the bottom, left, right.
4. I would like to use one layout which I was already built.

such a concept are, using renderingItem into view, than generating data in my component. here is concept I tried to do

```
<View style={styles.flatList}>
    <FlatList 
     data={newsFeedData} 
     horizontal={false} 
     showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false} 
     renderItem={({item, index})=>{ return
        <View>
            <TouchableOpacity 
             activeOpacity={1} 
             onPress={this.newsFeedCards.bind(this)}>
                <View style={styles.mgView}>
                    <ListItem item={item} image={item} index={index}/>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        }}/>
</Animated.View>

<View data={newsFeedData} 
      style={styles.pageDetail} 
      renderItem={(item, idex)=>{ 
      return <PageDetail 
              item={item} image={item} image={item}></PageDetail>
    }}>
</View>
```

Please help me anyone know the trick of this concept. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I didn't recognize your issues. Can you elaborate some more explanation ?

Comment: what this issues is with the flatlist know and generate items in order base on my JSON data's order. With this same order I would like to display the items into my other component. do you know any navigator support this issue? I've been looking for react-navigation, react router which hopefully provide the feature.